# Combining must_not in ElasticSearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently struggling with an ElastSearch query which currently looks the following:

```
...
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "bool-facet.criteria1": {
                        "value": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "bool-facet.criteria2": {
                        "value": false
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
...
```

So now when either criteria1 OR criteria2 matches, the documents are ignored. How must the query look like so that only documents that match criteria1 AND criteria2 are ignored?

Comment: which version ?!

Comment: This is kind of confusing, so must_not(A,B) means -(A OR B) = -A AND -B, or does it mean -(A AND B) = -A OR -B ? Then you speak about those that are ignored, so the negation of the negation, not(must_not(A,B)) means --(A OR B) = A OR B, or does it mean --(A AND B) = A AND B? Maybe you can clarify. I guess when I do the logic then the right interpretation is that it matches if -A AND -B. And then even more confusing you are actually looking for the values to be FALSE, so another negation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since updating elasticsearch version was not possible I had to find another solution. This is what worked for me:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not" : [
            {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                               "term": {
                                 "bool-facet.criteria1": false
                               }
                            },
                            {
                               "term": {
                                 "bool-facet.criteria2": false
                               }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In version 5.5.1, I get a parse error with the following reason: "no [query] registered for [query]"

Comment: I believe, inside 'must_not' there is no need write 'query' again. The inner 'must' clause can be written directly under 'must_not'. Not sure if its good practice or not.

edit: aahh.. its already mentioned in below's answer.

Answer (score 34):

If you want simple `AND`-behavior, then just nest another `bool` query inside of it:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must_not": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "bool-facet.criteria1": false
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "bool-facet.criteria2": false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that by using the `filter` (as it's a yes/no question with no scoring needed, but if you wanted scoring, then you would use `must` instead of `filter`) you get the desired `AND` behavior. This changes the question to "not(any document that has criteria1 == false AND criteria2 == false)".

Comment: This results in the following error for me:
 bool query does not support [filter]

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Seems to be 1.4.5... you mean its possible with a later version?

Comment: ok, i see this is a feature of 2.+ versions. i will try it out with the latest version.

Comment: It was possible in order versions using a more convoluted syntax. But since it sounds like you're starting out, I would start with the latest version (if not even starting with a 5.0 alpha release if you're in development).

Comment: In 5.5.1, this did not work. It did not give me an error, but I saw documents in the results which should have been filtered out by the `must_not`.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo If that's the case, then you should submit a bug with example data and the query to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch

Comment: In 7.X, this did not work. It did not give me an error, but I saw documents in the results which should have been filtered out by the `must_not`

Answer (score 17):

The following arrangement worked for me on a similar query in 5.5.1:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "bool":{
                    "must_not":{
                        "term":{
                            "bool-facet.criteria1": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "bool":{
                    "must_not":{
                        "term":{
                            "bool-facet.criteria2": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The other answers may have been correct for other versions, but did not work for me in 5.5.1.

Comment: not working in 7.X. good that you mentioned your version in the answer!

Comment: `!(x and y)` which was the question can be translated to `!x or !y`, so it seems to me your answer should have `should` instead of `must` on the top + minShouldClauses = 1, as `must` = `and`. But I haven't tried it.

Comment: I'll gladly welcome an edit if there's an easy change that makes it work with 7.x. I'd recommend appending the 7.x query after the 5.x query so the reader can see the difference. If it's more complicated (like explaining should vs must) then you might want to add it as your own answer with longer explanation (and get SO points for it too).

Answer (score 2):

This behavior worked for me under `6.5.4`:

```
GET model/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "field1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "field2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "field3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```