# ElasticSearch must_not to as a filter on array of items

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building an elasticsearch query which gets a query of items by geo bounds.

I want to filter the list to only contain items which do not match item attributes of `id` and `accountOwner`.

So I may get returned a list of items from elasticsearch

```
[{
        "account": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "first"
    },
    {
        "account": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "second"
    },
    {
        "account": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "second"
    }
]
```

I want to pass into the query a filter which says do not include in my returned list items that match `[{account:1,id:2}]` (yes, this needs to be an array)

What I am looking to get back from ElasticSearch is the above list, but without the one item in the above array.

I've been trying to decipher this in the docs, but didn't quite find what I was looking for.

My query (which may not be relevant to the question) is

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "100km",
                    "start": {
                        "lat": -37.8642399,
                        "lon": 144.9732028
                    }
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [{
                "id": 2,
                "account": 1
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

So to be clear, I only want to remove items that don't match on both account AND id

Comment: Is your list of items a `nested` field in your mapping?

Comment: This might be your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640784/combining-must-not-in-elasticsearch-query

Comment: @Val no they are not `nested` based on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Then, you'll have to if you want to achieve what you expect :-)