# Elasticsearch PHP assoc array with same key name

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I need to filter out certain words from my elasticsearch result. I am using must_not to achieve this. It works if I use one word/phrase at a time, but if I have multiple different words/phrases, then I can't add to the associative array in php because the field name that's being filtered is the same. How can I go about this?

Edit: for clarity, the words that are to be filtered out need to be loaded in dynamically. So I am looking to use a php function to add to ['body']['query']['bool']['must_not']['term'] however this can not be achieved because php will not allow for the same key name to be used.

```
'index' => 'indexName',
'body'  => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must'=>[
                'query_string' => [
                    'query' => "MyPhrase",
                    'fields' => ['description','vendorName'],
               
                ]
            ],
            'must_not'=>[
                'term' => [ 'field1'=>'myWord', 'field1'=>'myWord2'  
                ]
            ],
```

Comment: Ok, I got the answer. I used a different method for must not. While the one used above works, the other one proposed in this solution (by Mnebuerquo) is better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640784/combining-must-not-in-elasticsearch-query

Comment: If you found a solution please provide it as an answer and accept it.